# Firebase Authentication Staging Environment

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, staging, test-environments

I find nowhere in the docs how to setup a separate development (pre-production, staging, etc.) environment when working with Firebase Authentication. I do not want to create and delete arbitrary user accounts and be sending emails using my live provider while I'm developing or testing. Does that make sense?